# Delete top 1 row using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a SQL, the purpose is to keep the last two entries and delete the top rows .

```
delete from table 
where RowID in (select top 10 RowID from table)
```

This deletes all rows instead of the first rows I intend to delete.

In the interface I am using, 'WITH' command does not work. It has to be something like the above query.

I have a table with 3 columns `x, y, z`. I can't rely on the pseudo column rownum as when I delete some rows the rownum don't change. As this delete query will be running every 60 sec and the rownum of the table won't start from 1 every time.

I want to delete all other rows except the last two entries. `Top` will work

```
delete from custom.colperformance 
where RowID in (select top 2 RowID 
                from custom.colperformance 
                order by RowID desc)
```

This is giving me an error

```
    Table structure 

ProfileTime   TriggerTime  RowId
12            3             4
12            5             6
6             7             2
```

here Rowid comes in random if we delete some rows in between

Please help!! .. thanks in advance

Comment: using top without order by does not make much sense

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: How do you define "first" rows?

Comment: ***What*** error do you get? Also: table structure would be nice ....

Comment: parse failure : error at order by ,is the error

Answer (score 4):

If this is oracle you can not use TOP 10, use following syntax:

```
delete from table where RowID in (select RowID from table where rownum <= 10)
```

Of course you should also give order by

```
delete from table where RowID in (select RowID from table where rownum <= 10 ORDER BY table.columnX)
```

Comment: Oracle has pseudo columns named rowid and rownum.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur, you need to `ORDER BY` a column first, then get the `rownum`. Also you want `<=` rather than `<` since `rownum` starts with 1.

Comment: @DavidFaber I fixed <= problem but other than that this query works in oracle as it is.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur, my apologies. I am surprised to find out that putting `rownum` prior to `ORDER BY` is logically equivalent in Oracle to using a subquery with `ORDER BY` followed by `rownum`. Trying to wrap my brain around that one. This link from Tom Kyte, though, suggests that is not the case: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Ahh, I see now. The two aren't logically equivalent. I just ran it on a table in my local DB; it "worked" sorting on the primary key, but not on a different column. Your query might "work" as-is, but it isn't necessarily getting the "first" ten rows.

Comment: First 10 rows isn't a problem,all I want is to use order by in the query .but still am getting the error , even after using the primary key

Comment: @anjali your query is not correct for oracle. Please give us error message.

Comment: Error : Parse failure on line 1 of statement 'CHECK STATEMENT 'delete from custom.colperformance where RowID in (select RowID from custom.colperformance where Triggertime =3 order by RowID )" at or near 'order'

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table_name LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This does not take into account the RowID field mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

first select the top 1 from the entire table, then select the top one from the entire table where you leave out the result of the first query

```
select top 1 (RowID) 
from table 
where RowID NOT IN (select top 1 RowID from table)
```

now you know which rows you do not want to delete. save in temp table maybe?

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the below code

Let the table name be 'demo' then the code should be:

`DELETE from demo where id = (SELECT id FROM demo limit 1);`

You do not need to provide id manually.
Make sure to order the table accordingly.